# program launched with mpirun (1 node) is twice slow

Tags: c++, multithreading, mpi

I wanted to use MPI in order to execute a C++ program in parallel on multiple node. 
I just started to implement the initialization and destruction of the MPI environment (MPI::Init_thread and MPI::Finalize()). Then I compiled and executed my program with mpirun on one node (just for testing purpose) but I noticed a important slow down. The same program not launched via mpirun (command line in a terminal) is almost twice as fast.

This is the piece of code I have added to my application so far :

```
int provided = MPI::Init_thread( MPI_THREAD_FUNNELED );

if (provided!=MPI_THREAD_FUNNELED) {
    std::cerr << "Unable to init MPI " << provided << std::endl ;
    return 1 ;
} else {
    std::cout << "provided  " << provided << " Expected " <<  MPI_THREAD_FUNNELED << std::endl ;
}
MPI::Finalize();
```

My program is already a multithreaded  application using the thread library of C++11. For all the test I have done and for what I read on the web, this should not be issue.

I also noticed that during the compilation cmake is using gcc instead of mpic++. So I  compiled my project manually but it does not change the execution time.

Do you know why I am getting such slow down when I am using mpirun ?
Do you know some tools that could help investigate this kind is issue ?

Technical details :

- gcc version : 4.8.2
- mpi implementation : openmpi v 1.8.1
- kernel  : 2.6.32-504.30.3.el6.x86_64
- OS : CentOS 6.6

Thank you for your help

Regards

Comment: *cmake is using gcc instead of mpic++* makes me wonder what *mpic++*, which is itself a compiler-wrapper, is using.  Probably irrelevant to your question, but a source of variation you should eliminate.

Comment: did you try callgrind? How many processes/threads are you launching?

Comment: So far, i have been working with two threads (the final objective is to have 16 thread per node). I already profiled my application with the "perf" tool and  whatsoever the application is launched, I have the same percentage for the main libraries. I also try to use callgrind but it is not able to see what happens behind mpirun, so it does not returned interesting result

Comment: I may have found the solution by re-reading the official documentation of openmpi : [link]http://www.open-mpi.org/doc/v1.8/man1/mpirun.1.php. It is written : <If your application uses threads, then you probably want to ensure that you are either not bound at all (by specifying --bind-to none)>. So I add the option "bind-to none" to my command line and it is seems to work great.

Comment: @clam37 You can answer your own question so that others can find the solution easily.